# Do we vote to close questions with high vote counts?

Tags: discussion

Another question regarding close votes (since I have seen so many populating the review queues recently) - **how should we approach/evaluate closing questions which have relatively high vote counts?**

Clearly, if questions have made it to the review queue then a reviewer has flagged it as potentially off topic, in need of additional details or clarity, etc. However, if questions have vote counts of 2-3 or higher should we pay special attention to this? Clearly, some members of the community have expressed interest in the question for its usefulness or are interested in seeing it answered.

Does this mean that these types of questions should "generally" be left open or commented on before closing due to their potential usefulness to the community?

My procedure has been mostly to just close these so far. Interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: There is no automatism that suggests upvoted question couldn't/shouldn't not be closed. If you have a good reason for a close vote, then that's that. However, multiple upvotes may give you pause and make you put some additional thought into your decision.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.